# Angular 5 Does not work on IE9

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-9

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iz3mq.jpg)I have Angular Apps that works fine on IE11,
But when I run it on IE9 I got the following error

> observable error: Error: Access is denied.
>
> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'apply' 
>   localhost:4200, line 1 character 1

It fails in the following

```
const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'POST, GET, OPTIONS',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'});
    let RetCaseNumner=''
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this.url, this.jsonBody, options)
            .map((res: Response) => {           
            let ret =JSON.parse(res.text())
            let ResponseBody =   ret.EventMessageResponse.Response.ResponseBody
            xml2js.parseString(ResponseBody,function(err, result){
                RetCaseNumner =result.Result.CaseNumber[0]
                return RetCaseNumner;
            });
            return RetCaseNumner
        })
    .do(data => console.log('Inside do Case Number: ' + (data)))
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

Here is my pollyfills.ts

```
// This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
// You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
//This get rid of SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'apply'
import 'core-js/es7/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-set';
import 'core-js/es6/typed';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

import 'core-js/es6/reflect';

import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
(window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;

import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
// If you need to support the browsers/features below, uncomment the import
// and run `npm install import-name-here';
// Learn more in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html

// Needed for: IE9
// import 'classlist.js';

// Animations
// Needed for: All but Chrome and Firefox, Not supported in IE9
// import 'web-animations-js';

// Date, currency, decimal and percent pipes
// Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11 and Safari 10
// import 'intl';
// import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';

// NgClass on SVG elements
// Needed for: IE10, IE11
 import 'classlist.js';



/**
 * rxjs
 */
import 'rxjs/bundles/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/throttleTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeInterval';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

//This get rid of SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'apply'
// import '@angular/core/bundles/core.umd';
import '@angular/common/bundles/common.umd';
import '@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd';
import '@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd';
import '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd'
import 'ie9-oninput-polyfill';
import 'angular-polyfills/dist/blob';
import 'angular-polyfills/dist/classlist';
import 'angular-polyfills/dist/formdata';
import 'angular-polyfills/dist/intl';
import 'angular-polyfills/dist/shim';
import 'angular-polyfills/dist/typedarray';
import 'console-polyfill';
```

What Did I do wrong ?
Did I miss something ?

Comment: Are you using Angular CLI? Never had a problem with IE 9+ just using that as standard and installing what it says to in the polyfills file (including the npm install). Try looking at a fresh project's file and go from there.

Comment: Thanks Bagley,I started a fresh new Angular CLI project and uncomment the pollyfills for IE9 but the same code works fine in IE11 and on IE9 raise Access is denied and SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'apply'

Comment: From a quick overview it looks like the error isn't coming from where you are thinking, and could be somewhere else in your code. The code you posted has no errors, and should work fine in ie 9+ as long as it's not run in strict mode. Unless you have this as a client requirement I'd suggest to let it be. ie 11 is considered the last non-deprecated version of ie browser. Anything below has security hazards and shouldn't be used is the general idea.

Comment: Do what microsoft did... stop supporting old browsers

Answer (score 0):

IE < 10 does not have CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) support. If you have code that is sending an AJAX call using CORS, you will not be able to support IE < 11.

Supposedly IE 10 has support for CORS, but it was still throwing errors in my case. I tried to implement some xdomain solutions but I couldn't get that to work either. IE was just too buggy.

I would recommend not supporting IE since MS has seemed to abandon it anyway. Since I haven't seen any elegant ways of doing that posted anywhere, I'll go ahead and put my workaround here:

You can detect Internet Explorer < 10 using apache, so I created a special landing page that I redirect all IE < 10 traffic to.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*MSIE.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) ie.html

</IfModule>
```

In order to make sure that file is included in the build, make sure to add it to your assets block in .angular-cli.json:

```
... 
"apps": [
{
  ...
  "assets": [
    ...
    "ie.html"
  ],
```